# If I use too many Facades will it effect the performace?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have many facades so will it slow down the performances?
Or if I want to use some classes on some controller so how should I do it, I mean good practises

Answer (score 1):

Facades are just another way to call instances storted in the Dependency Injection Container of Laravel. They are available throughout the entire application.

Dependency injected instances instead are only available where you declare them, making your class better ordered.

```
use Dependency;

class Class
{
    public function foo()
    {
        return Dependency::foo();
    }
}
```

I personally find this approach messier and you can struggle to understand where the dependency actually comes from unless you go search directly in the code.

```
use Author\Library\Dependency;

class Class
{
    public function __construct(Dependency $dependency)
    {
        $this->dependency = $dependency;
    }

    public function foo()
    {
        return $this->dependency->foo();
    }
}
```

This approach, instead, gives you a direct information of the instance that needs to be used inside the class.

In terms of good practises, I believe it's just a matter of preference, even though Laravel 4.x was heavily based on Facades, but now on 5.x much less.

In terms of performance, you shouldn't see any difference except of an *additional class X instance* autoloaded in Composer.